# Testcafe: .includes() is not a function when used in an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to use an if/else statement on one of my Testcafe cases but the condition is to see if a string contains a word (substring) and if it does run if not go to else

Here is an example code:

```
const textData = Selector('.css-f3fafa').innerText;

        if (textData.includes("Administrator") ) {
            await t
            .hover(button1)
            .expect(button).eql('Submit')
            .click(buttonUp)
            .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
            .click(modalSub)
            .wait(5000)
            .expect(thank).eql('Thank you for your submission.')

        } else {
            await t
            // .hover(button1)
            // .expect(button).eql('Sign Up')
            .expect(textData).contains('Administrator')
            .click(button1)
            .expect(getStarted).ok('Get Started')
        }
```

I keep getting a type error: `textData.includes... is not a function` but if I did `.expect(textData).includes...` that works just fine and it passes. I also tried `indexOf`, adding `a === true` to the condition, I tried adding `String()` to the variable and that kinda worked but it skipped right to the else (Doesn't pass the If even when the condition is true)

Is there another way I can make this condition work with Testcafe?

Comment: What's the actual data type of `textData`? It sounds like it's not a string for some reason.

What happened when you tried `indexOf`? Did you get an error?

Comment: I get the same error as well; here's the actual element <p class="css-f3fafa">Data Reviewer, Administrator, Tester</p>

Comment: @DjKniteX: Could you post back on how you got this to work please?  I am facing the same problem but unable to fix it using the steps from accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @Janaaaa; I got it to work with the example @Andreas posted!

Answer (score 6):

The DOM Node properties and methods are implemented as asynchronous getters.

> [Using Selectors | TestCafe -> Obtain Element
>   State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#obtain-element-state):
>
> *"Selectors and promises returned by selectors expose API to get the state (size, position, classes, etc.) of the matching element. See [DOM
>   Node State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html). **Note that these methods and property getters are asynchronous, so use await to obtain an element's property**."*

Examples from the documentation:

```js
const headerText = await Selector('#header').textContent;
```

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My fixture`
    .page('http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

const windowsInput = Selector('#windows');

test('Obtain Element State', async t => {
    await t.click(windowsInput);

    const windowsInputChecked = await windowsInput.checked; // returns true
});
```

Comment: I tried adding await to my const variable and that didn't work as well; I got this    1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified
      selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

Comment: The message is clear. There's no (or maybe not yet) element that would match the given selector. If there is a matching element then check the documentation.

Comment: I think I got it to work; Imma try with another condition but what I did was copied your steps pretty much (with my classnames) like having the const right after await t.click and then before the if else and it seemed to work so far